# WCF - Application is using client's app.config rather than WCF service's app.config

Tags: wcf, app-config

In my VS solution, I created a console project, which I'm using as the client, and an empty project for the WCF service.

I then created the WCF service (created my contract and service type and manually constructed the app.config), and added a reference to the WCF service project in the client project.

However, when I called ServiceHost.Open() in the client, the endpoints weren't loading.  I eventually determined that I needed to put all of the config information in the Client's app.config, rather than the service's app.config.

I'm not sure if this is normal, or if I'm doing something wrong.  In the past, when I've used the WCF project template, this wasn't the case.

Comment: The config is taken from the config file for the HOST PROCESS, i.e. if you host you WCF service in ASP.NET site, then the config comes from web.config. This is where many people get confused: if you have a class-lib assembly that has some config to it, it will not be the one that .NET config will be fed from. So look for server config in your web app (if you use ASP-hosting), and app.config for console client.
 Why do you call Host.Open() on client?

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't aware of that.  I'm working through "Windows Communication Foundation Unleashed" and I haven't generated the metadata yet, so I was just using ServiceHost to confirm that everything was loading correctly.  I wanted to work this issue out first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is normal. Each .NET application (client, service, web site, etc.) has it's own configuration file. To be precise, there's a hierarchy of them, but the bottom end of that hierarchy is unique to the application.

This makes sense if you think about it -- the client would need to contact the service to ask for it's configuration, but it needs to know the endpoint information in order to even try to do that. So yes, the normal process is that client and service both have very similar information in their configuration files.

If you use Visual Studio's built-in tooling to do everything for you, it will automatically create and/or edit the configuration file for your client when you add a Service Reference to the project, copying from the metadata endpoint that WCF exposes for that purpose. Alternatively, you can use the WCF configuration editor tools to edit your client application.

Also, note that nothing actually enforces that your client and server have compatible settings; e.g. you can change the maximum sizes of many buffers/graphs/etc on one side, and not the other, and see some strange behavior. It's up to you to make sure both ends are working with mutually usable settings.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  With your explanation, it makes perfect sense.  In the past, I have used Visual Studio's built-in tooling.  I wanted to get a deeper understanding of how the config's are built, and things of that nature.  If I hadn't done all of this manually, I wouldn't have leaned all of this :).

Comment: No problem. Remember to mark the most helpful answer as "accepted" to keep the site running smoothly :)